# Sparse boolean tags: many columns or multiple tables?

Tags: normalization

I'm pretty new to database design. I'm storing records which are tagged with some (few) of a (large) number of possible tags (much like StackExchange questions). At the moment I have a single table with one record per row and one column per tag, very simple.

But then I read that ["a well-normalized database will never need more than 100 columns in a table"](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html), which clashes with my approach of simply adding a new column every time a new type of tag is created.

I guess that the alternative is to have one table per tag, and to JOIN when I want to work out which tags a particular record has. When I create a new tag I'd make a new table rather than a new column.

At what point should I normalise? Clearly if I have millions of possible tags, and each record has only ~10 tags selected, then I'm wasting space by storing the sparse columns. Is there another disadvantage to continually adding columns to a simple table?

Is there an objective answer to this? Does it depend on frequency of new tag-type creation? Or sparsity? "100 columns" seems like a very arbitrary limit.

If it makes a difference I'm using SQLite.

Comment: I think you need to consider a 3 table/one-to-many relationship.   Have your base table with the record you are going to tag (with an PK/ID), a second table with an entry for each tag (with a PK/ID) and then a joining table that references the base table's PK/ID to the tag table's PK/ID.

Comment: Your table has one column per tag (i.e., the DBA.SE `post` table would have columns `sql-server`, `postgresql`, `oracle`, `mysql`, `normalization`, etc, and this post would have NULL for the first four, and `1` for the last)? Or, you have several types of tags, and each row can have one tag of that type (i.e., `post` would have a `DBMS` column which could be `mysql`, `oracle`, etc, but would be NULL for this post, and a `DBTheory` column which could have values like `database-design`, and for this post would have `normalization`)? or, something else? Trying to envision the set-up here.

Comment: @RDFozz At the moment the table has one column per tag, as you describe, but (if it makes a difference) I have 0/1 instead of NULL/1. In the longer-term we may want to group tags but we're not doing that right now.